# Powermockito: argument matching for HashMap

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have a function as follows:

```
class A {

  static funcA(HashMap<String, Boolean> h);  

}
```

I have to mock this method funcA
So, I am doing

```
PowerMockito.when(A.funcA(anyObject());
```

Now, I am getting the error that the funcA is not applicable to Object. How can i get a matching for a hashmap, like anyString(), or anyInt() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
any(HashMap.class)
```

which should match any instance of the class you specify (which is `HashMap` in this example)

Comment: even though i followed your appraoch, the powermockito enters the statis function, and throws a null pointer exception because the hash map it needs is not there. however, since I am mocking the method, why should powermockito enter it function definition?